# How To use Rendering plugin in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using the Rendering plugin for creating PDFs. The plugin is working fine. However, when I click on download as PDF. It redirects me to another page:

[image: Screenshot of the other page]

It gives me a result in PDF format and then it gives me an option for saving as in this image:
[image: Screenshot of saving as PDF]

But what I want is when I click on the download as PDF button:
[image: Download button]

That it will show me a save window directly rather than redirecting me to another page.

My code:

```
def renderFormPDF(Long id){
        def empinstance= emp.get(id)
        renderPdf(template:"view", model:[empinstance:empinstance, pdfRendering:true])
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def renderFormPDF(Long id){
    def empinstance= emp.get(id)

    response.setContentType("application/pdf")
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName.pdf")

    renderPdf(template:"view", model:[empinstance:empinstance, pdfRendering:true])
}
```